# Create a String variable from a URL using JSoup and Regex in Java?

Tags: java, jsoup

So I am trying to make a program that retrieves the IFrame tag from a website, opens the link and downloads the video. Currently, it retrieves the IFrame tag, but I can't figure out how to ***ignore the actual tags***. I am pretty sure I can use the .split() feature, but I don't know how to create a regex code to only pull the data from inside of the quotes. I also tried using JSoup's .html, but it just printed a blank statement. Here is what I have (It mostly split correctly, except in the URL there is "id=..." which causes it to split again):

```
package com.trentmenard;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document website;
        try{
            website = Jsoup.connect("https://swordartonlineepisode.com/sword-art-online-season-3-episode-1-english-dubbed-watch-online/").get();
            System.out.println("Website Found!  Title: " + website.title());

            Element videoLink = website.select("iframe").first();

            System.out.println("Found Video Link: " + videoLink);
            videoLink.removeAttr("width");
            videoLink.removeAttr("height");
            videoLink.removeAttr("scrolling");
            videoLink.removeAttr("allowfullscreen");

            System.out.println("Modified: " + videoLink);

            String link = videoLink.toString();
            String[] stringArray = link.split("=");

            for(String a : stringArray){
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXTiV.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you not just getting the `src` attribute of the `iframe` `Element`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize I could do it that way. Sorry, this is my first time using JSoup. How would I select the ```src```?

Comment: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks!

Comment: You can't get this value from javascript using Jsoup. You can use regular expressions but that's not the nicest solution. Let's take a different approach. Look at that URL. It contains  `id=MTEzMzQ1`. If you search HTML you will find out it's kept in a hidden input `<input type="hidden" id="id" value="MTEzMzQ1">` so you should try to get that id and use this string in your URL.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work! How did you know that there was a hidden input? If anyone wants the code I used:
        `try{
            website = Jsoup.connect(iFrameLink).get();
            Element textAndJavaScript = website.getElementById("id");
            redirectLink = textAndJavaScript.attr("value");
            System.out.println("Grabbing Hidden Element ID With Value: " + redirectLink);
            System.out.println("Grabbing Download Link: " + baseURLDownload + redirectLink);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`